# What is the point of this factory class in this C++ video?

Tags: c++

[see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyXaK.png)

What is the point of the DogFactory class? All it does is implement static functions to create specific types of dogs, but why not just write that yourself?

For example, instead of

```
Dog* ptr = DogFactory::createYellowDog();
```

why not

```
Dog* ptr = new YellowDog();
```

It's more clear and shorter and easier.

Of course in practice you'd do something like

```
std::unique_ptr<Dog> ptr = std::make_unique(YellowDog());
```

but either way, still much better than using the DogFactory.

Comment: It depends, the video shows only some random code examples but in real world code there are reason for those kinds of patterns (factory, singleton...). It's true what you say but it's also true that you have to analyze the code in the context in witch it's been written

Comment: For example, you can create `static Dog* clone() const { return new Dog(*this); }` which is the same as calling the copy constructor on a function. This is needed in some case but it depends on what you're doing/what you need

Comment: just my opinion, but if you have `createXXX`, you'd better have a coupled `deleteXXX` functoin. (instead of using `delete` operator in your picture)

Answer (score 1):

Typical situation would be that `Dog` is part of public library interface while `YellowDog` is one the private implementations supplied by library. User code is not aware of particular implementation selected by library and only uses public interface `Dog` and public factory function to produce instances. This way implementation of `YellowDog` inside of library can be modified without requiring any changes in user code.